# Eucalyptus FastStart ISO

Tags: eucalyptus

I have a bit of a stupid question. I am trying to install Eucalyptus Fast Start and the installation guide states that you must have access to the Eucalyptus FastStart ISO.
It then directs you to the following link:
http://www.eucalyptus.com/download/faststart 
However this only gives me documentation on the installation process.

Does anyone know where I can find the relevant ISO files to download? I have been searching for the last number of hours with no luck.

Thanks in advance,
Amy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like FastStart ISO has been removed. But the RPMs are still in the repository. So, if you have a CentOS 7.3 machine, you can try using a bash script from www.eucalyptus.com/install to drive an all-in-one installation:

```
bash <(curl -Ls http://www.eucalyptus.com/install)
```

Or you can follow the full installation instructions, of course:

https://docs.eucalyptus.com/eucalyptus/latest/#install-guide/index.html

Admittedly that's more work than booting up an ISO.

Comment: Thank you for the response, appreciate it.